# Hi I tried communication between components through services in angular 2 but returning function returns empty values

Tags: angular, service

Second component of the page where i need to get the values from the first component

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {AppService} from './app.service';
    import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';    

@Component({
 template:
 `
        <h1>second component</h1>
        <h1>second component</h1>
        <p>{{myName}}</p>
 `,
 providers:[AppService]
            })

export class SecondComponent {      

    constructor(private appservice: AppService)
                    {
                        this.appservice=appservice;
                        this.myName=this.appservice.getDat();
                        console.log(this.myName);       
                    }    
                            }
```

** this is the first component page from where i need to pass the value to the second component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'; 
import {AppService} from '../second/app.service';
import { Router }   from '@angular/router';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from '../app.route';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({

  selector: 'first-app',
  templateUrl:"../app/src/component/first/app.firstpage.html",
  providers:[AppService]              
          })

export class FirstComponent 
{      
    data:any;      

    public edited=false;
    public city=false;
    public dateCon=false;

    inputForm: FormGroup;
    Select: FormControl;
    Selectt: FormControl;
    dat:FormControl;

  constructor(private appservice:AppService,builder: FormBuilder, router:Router)     
  {
              this.appservice.getData().subscribe(res=>{this.data=res.json()});
              console.log(this.data);
              this.Select = new FormControl('', [
                Validators.required
                                                  ]);
              this.Selectt = new FormControl('', [
                Validators.required
                                                ]);
              this.dat = new FormControl('', [
                Validators.required
                                                  ]);
              this.inputForm = builder.group({
              Select: this.Select,
              Selectt: this.Selectt,
              dat: this.dat
                                            });
              this.router=router;
              this.appservice=appservice;    
          } 

   ngOnInit(){
           this.appservice.getData()
             }

     onclick(a,b) {
          console.log(this.data);
          let sel1=this.inputForm.value.Select;
          let sel2=this.inputForm.value.Selectt;
          let sel3=this.inputForm.value.dat;
          console.log(sel3);
          console.log(sel1);
          console.log(sel2);
          console.log(this.data.bus.length);
            for(let i=0;i<this.data.bus.length;i++){
                  if((this.data.bus[i].from==sel1)&&(this.data.bus[i].to==sel2))
                                            {
      /*this.appservice.setData(this.data.bus[i]);*/     
                      this.appservice.setData(i);
                      console.log(i);
                                            }
                                                    }

                  if((sel1!="")&&(sel2!="")&&(sel3!="")&&(sel1!=sel2))
                  {
                          this.router.navigate(['/sec-component']);
                  }
                  else if((sel1=="")&&(sel2=="")&&(sel3==""))
                    {
                          this.edited=true;
                    }
                  if((sel1==sel2)&&((sel1!="")&&(sel2!="")))
                    {
                            this.edited=false;
                            this.city=true;
                    }
                  else 
                   {
                          this.city=false;
                     }
                  if(sel1!=sel2)
                     {
                          this.edited=false;
                     }
                  if(sel3=="")
                       {
                            this.dateCon=true;
                       }
                  else  
                   {        
                            this.dateCon=false;
                       }
 }       
}
```

**Service.ts values not getting reflected in the below return function the sharingData.name is getting empty values on consoling it.**

```
import {Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

export interface myData 
{
   name:number;
}

@Injectable()
export class AppService 
{   
        sharingData: myData={name};
                setData(i)
                         {
                             console.log('save data function called' + i + this.sharingData.name);
                             this.sharingData.name=i; 
                             console.log(this.sharingData.name);
                         }

                getDat()
                        {
                            console.log(this.sharingData.name);
                            return this.sharingData.name;
                        }

        constructor(private http:Http){}

                 getData()
                        {
                            return this.http.get('./app/src/component/busDet.json')

                        }    
}
```

**module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import {AppService} from './second/app.service';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.route';
import { AppComponent }    from './app.component';
import { FirstComponent }  from './first/first.component';
import { SecondComponent }  from './second/second.component';
import { ThirdComponent }  from './third/third.component';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,HttpModule,JsonpModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstComponent,
    SecondComponent,
    ThirdComponent 
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders, AppService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your chances of getting a helpful answer are much higher if you improve the quality of your question. The code is hard to read, it would be great if you could improve it to make it more readable (for example remove all the redundant whit spaces).

Comment: Looking at your excerpt: `constructor(private appservice: AppService) { this.appservice=appservice;`. This is not necessary; when you make a variable `private` in your constructor, it's already added to the `this.` context. Don't overwrite that.

Comment: This will not work out correctly btw: `this.appservice.getData().subscribe(res=>{this.data=res.json()});
              console.log(this.data);`, since the logging will be called before the  http request finishes and calls the given callback.

Comment: what to do to rectify it? How to get the data?

Comment: I think @rinukkusu ment that console.log(this.data) should be included into subscribe method.

Comment: Yeah i do tried doing that console is working properly now...still i could not able to return the value from the service....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried removing providers:[appservice] from the first component.and it started working fine.(it was actually injecting the service again which made the sharingData to become null.)

Answer (score 0):

Register your service in application module (common module for your components), and remove registration from components.

Comment: From the way that the code's been set up, I get the feeling he's been following an older tutorial or using an older version of Angular2.

Comment: @Bjorn Schijff As I understand hierarchy of injectors of Angular2, he could setup component like he did, but in that case he told angular to create a new instance of service only in scope of that component and its child components.

Comment: Yes regirstered, my problem is that it is getting reflected in setData(i) in service.ts but not getting into getDat() in the same service.while i tried to console it is returning actual value in serData() but empty value in getDat().

Comment: Did you remove registration from components?

Comment: tried doing that but its showing error since AppService is not being recognized.

Comment: If it's not being recognized, you should add it on the module level, not the component level. This will dependency inject it once, so you get to "talk" to the same instance.

Comment: It is added on module level still getting error when removed from component

Comment: added module.ts

Comment: I suggest in service's constructor write console.log('Service created') and check how many times Angular creates your service. If it is created 2 times the you get different inctances of your service. If not, then there's might be something that clears your sharingData

Comment: It is created only once.

Comment: It seems like this.myName=this.appservice.getDat(); is called before you set sharingData.name because of http request

Comment: You call this.appservice.setData(i); after click event, but call this.appservice.getDat() immediately in constructor of the component, when this.sharingData.name is not initialized

Comment: after getting the values in the setdata it is going to firstcomponent and after it is coming to getval and returning the null value.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your help,tried removing providers:[appservice] from the first component.and it started working fine.(it was actually injecting the service again which made the sharingData to become null.)